# Why "if $(ps aux | grep ...)" always succeeds in Bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Why the following `if` statement succeeds ?

```
if $(ps aux | grep -q "bla bla") ; then echo "found" ; fi
```

Comment: If your run `ps aux | grep "bla bla"` you will see why...

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965887/command-substitution-in-if-statement-condition).

Comment: `if pgrep -f "bla bla"; then echo "found"; fi`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because the `grep` process itself is being returned by `ps`.  You can "trick" `grep` to not match itself by surrounding one of the search characters in a character class `[ ]` which doesn't change the functionality: 
Just do:

```
if ps aux | grep -q "[b]la bla" ; then echo "found" ; fi
```

Also, the use of process substitution `$()` is unnecessary.  The `if` will work on the success of the last command in the pipe chain, which is what you want.

*Note*: The reason the character class trick works is because the `ps` output still has the character class brackets but when `grep` is processing the search string, it uses the brackets as syntax rather than a fixed string to match.

Comment: I got entirely too excited about this trick. :D  Piping to | grep -v grep always made me sad and now I don't have to do that anymore!

Answer (score 10):

If you grep the output from `ps aux`, you will always get a process showing your previous command. To fix this, you can pipe the output to grep twice, once to remove line with "grep" in it, and again for the process your looking for.

```
ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "Finder"
```

Answer (score 9):

the 'grep' process is already running by the time ps runs, so the ps output includes it.

Try using `pgrep` instead.

pgrep is precisely for this purpose:

`if pgrep "bla bla" ; then echo "found" ; fi`

Comment: Mr Downvoter, I have edited my answer for better clarity. Please see if it looks better now. Ta

Answer (score 2):

The `$(` is a small little bit relevant, and changes the meaning a bit. Although in this case, because there is never any output from `grep -q`, you can just about get away with the `$(`. You probably want to start with something like (as pointed out by others):

```
if ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep -q 'bla bla'; then
    echo 'Found'
fi
```

Anyway, you started with

```
if $(ps aux | grep -q "bla bla") ; then echo "found" ; fi
```

With `$(`, the command inside the `$( )` is executed and the output of that command is used as the command line for the outer command. Do these four experiments:

```
# if $(echo nonexistant ; true) ; then echo "found" ; fi
nonexistant: command not found

# if $(echo nonexistant ; false) ; then echo "found" ; fi
nonexistant: command not found

# if $(echo  ; true) ; then echo "found" ; fi
found

# if $(echo  ; false) ; then echo "found" ; fi
```

So, according to this you will output get `found` if both these conditions hold:

- The command inside the `$( )` created no output
- *and* the command was succesful

This suggests that `ps aux | grep -q "bla bla"` was successful and created no output. It's no surprise that `grep -q` creates no output. That's what the `-q` is for. So therefore, your command must have had a true status, which implies that the grep did successfully find a match. We know that `grep` will always find a match in this case, because the list of processes from `ps` will include `grep` itself; the grep will always find itself.

Comment: nice 'exploded' explanation of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter out the process that is `grep`ping for 'bla bla':

```
$ if ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep -q 'bla bla'; then
    echo 'Found'
fi
```

Comment: don't you want the -v grep after the target grep? (If I downvote, I say why).

Comment: I also got downvoted twice with no explanation. I think someone is downvoting very liberally on this question ...

Comment: @amir75 : looks liked all the downvotes have disappeared (again with no explanation!) ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Normally, yes, I would filter *after* the `grep`, but since we're calling `grep -q`, there's nothing to filter. I don't follow the downvote comments (there are no votes on this answer).