# Bash "booleans" default to true?

Tags: bash, boolean

I was messing around with bash true/false, and I noticed something non-standard:

```
$ if $varible_i_have_never_set_before; then echo yes; fi
yes
```

Bash empty variables seem to evaluate to true.  Usually uninitialized booleans are inherently false, at least in most modern programming languages.  Is there a good explanation for this?  Is there any way to get the desired functionality, short of string comparisons?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Look at the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973170/827263); it covers the case in this question.

Comment: The first question is pretty much a duplicate, but no one has answered the second one yet.  Should I ditch this sort of construct entirely or invert all my logic?  Neither option sounds fun.

Comment: In many languages, using an uninitialized variable either yields an unspecified result or causes undefined behavior. The fact that `if` with an unset variable is treated as a true condition is bizarre. I suggest the solution is; don't do that. You can either set the variable to either `true` or `false` (so `if $var ; then ...` invokes the appropriate built-in command), or you can use an explicit comparison like `if [ "$var" = "true" ] ; then ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to restrict myself to always initializing booleans,  because there should be no need to (and it makes the specific code I'm writing more complicated).  I'll just go back to `foo="true"` or `foo=""`, and test with `if [[ $foo ]]; ...`.  Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `if` does. It does not check the *contents* of the argument, it checks the *return value of the command*. Since there is no value in the variable, nothing is run. And, strange as it seems, this nothing being run has a return value of 0, which `if` considers true.

Answer (score 0):

And I imagine the internal Bash function that calls commands to be like.

```
int call_command(char * command, char ** args, int argc)
{
    int r = 0;  ## default, should actually be just u8.
    char * external_path = 0;
    if (command) {
        if (is_function(command)) {
            r = call_function(command, args, argc);
        }
        else if (is_builtin(command)) {
            r = call_builtin(command, args, argc);
        }
        else if ((external_path = check_if_external_command_and_get_absolute_path(command))) {
            r = call_external(external_path, args, argc);
        }
        else {
            printf("bash: %s: command not found\n", command);
            r = 127;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```