# Mac OSX, Bash, awk, and negative look behind

Tags: regex, macos, bash, awk

I want to find a particular process using awk:

```
ps aux|awk '/plugin-container.*Flash.*/'
```

Now it finds the process, but it includes itself in the results, because ps results include them as well. To prevent that, I am trying to use negative look behind as follows:

```
ps aux|awk '/(\?<!awk).*plugin-container.*Flash.*/'
```

But it does not work. Does awk support look behind? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you can use pipe (`|`) why not pipe it again with `grep -v awk`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8965530/207248

Comment: Two answerers say that they don't know whether awk supports lookbehind. It doesn't. OS X (and GNU) `grep` has a `-P` option which supports PCRE which provides lookbehind (and ahead, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common trick is to use

```
ps aux | grep '[p]lugin-container.*Flash.*'
```

The character class [p] prevents grep itself from being matched.

Comment: The same trick works in awk: `ps aux | awk '/[p]lugin-container.*Flash.*/'`

Comment: This works well, even with awk. Can you please explain how it works? Thanks

Comment: @Loke: I tried to explain it in the last line. `[p]` creates a character class that only the character `p` matches, thus `plugin` matches, but `[p]lugin` does not. In other words, you change the command line not to contain the string it searches for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether `awk` supports lookbehind, but I usually solve this problem with `grep -v`:

```
aix@aix:~$ ps aux | awk '/plugin-container.*Flash/' | grep -v awk
```

(Also, I'd normally use `grep` for the `awk` command above.)

Comment: The `awk` does not support lookaround pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if awk supports lookbehinds, but if, then the question mark at the start should not be escaped, a negative lookbehind starts `(?<!`

A question mark right after the opening bracket is the sign, that this group is not a capturing group, i.e. it has some special meaning.