# egrep gives me what I want, grep -E does not

Tags: shell, grep

I have read that egrep is deprecated in favour of grep -E so I'm looking back at my code and changing it where I find it.
But I see that the results are not always as expected.

With egrep, I get my list of running Oracle instances:

```
ps -ef|grep [p]mon|awk -F'ora_pmon_' '{print $NF}'|egrep -v 'ASM|^$'
halana
bila
halsasa
loana
```

However with grep -E, I get part of the awk in the results:

```
ps -ef|grep [p]mon|awk -F'ora_pmon_' '{print $NF}'|grep -Ev 'ASM|^$'
halana
bila
halsasa
 {print $NF}
loana
```

Excluding 'print' obviously works but is it the right way to go about it?:

```
ps -ef|grep [p]mon|awk -F'ora_pmon_' '{print $NF}'|grep -Ev 'ASM\|^$|print'
halana
bila
halsasa
loana
```

Is this effect due to the fact that grep -E allows additional regular expression syntax?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output also in your question to make it more clear, Thank you.

Comment: If you're actually getting part of the `awk` program in your results, that wouldn't have anything to do with `grep` (it can't reach back and somehow make `awk` produce unexpected output). That looks more like an `awk` failure, but without a reproducible example it's hard to tell.

Comment: Not sure, but may be related to `ps` including the processes of the commands being executed themselves (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965509/why-if-ps-aux-grep-always-succeeds-in-bash). As a workaround, why not remove the final grep and add it to `awk`? Something like `awk -F'ora_pmon_' 'NF && !/ASM/{print $NF}'` .. and perhaps remove both grep and use `awk -F'ora_pmon_' 'NF>1 && !/ASM/{print $NF}'` (guessing based on shown samples)

Comment: The surprise isn't that you see the `awk` command in your `ps` output when using `grep -E`; the surprise is that you _didn't_ ever get it using `egrep`. The original code was just as buggy as the new code is, insofar as it doesn't filter its own pipeline components out of the `ps` output. (That's part of why @DudyBoy's answer is a good one).

Comment: Remember, the point of `grep [p]mon` is to make that `grep` command itself not contain the string `pmon`, but then you have `ora_pmon` right there in your awk command! You'd need to make it `ora_[p]mon` or such in the awk to not have the bug.

Comment: Also, you should quote `[p]mon` -- otherwise the shell will change it to just `pmon` when you run the code in a directory that has a `pmon` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggesting to simplify your line, eliminate all `grep` commands:

```
pgrep -af 'pmon'|awk -F'ora_pmon_' '!/ASM|^$/{print $NF}'
```

Fold first `grep` command into `pgrep` command.

Fold second `grep` command into `awk` scirpt `!/ASM|^$/{print $NF}`

Comment: Hi Dudi. Thank you for that. It looks elegant. Unfortunately, I forgot to say I am using AIX. And that doesn't have a pgrep.

Comment: The alternative to `pgrep -af 'pmon'` in AIX is `ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep`  . Good luck.

Comment: @DudiBoy no, the alternative to `pgrep -af 'pmon'` is `ps -ef | grep '[p]mon'`.

Answer (score 2):

#### About `grep -E` vs `egrep`

There is no difference whatsoever between these commands (they're even provided by the same executable on most operating systems); *your old code was vulnerable to this bug too*, and if you didn't see it, that's just a matter of being "lucky" in `ps` getting enough of the process list read before the shell gets to setting up the `awk` part of the pipeline.

#### Solving Your Problem

The *right* answer is already [given by @DudiBoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71127541/14122), but the answer with the *smallest possible change* would be to make your `awk` (assuming it has GNU extensions and accepts regexes in the field separator specification) escape the string `pmon` the same way your first grep command does:

```
ps -ef|grep '[p]mon'|awk -F'ora_[p]mon_' '{print $NF}'|grep -Ev 'ASM|^$'
```

Comment: All awks accept a regexp as the **field** separator, you're probably confusing it's availability with a regexp as the **record** separator which only some awks such as GNU awk allow.